# Custom Type add Transitions

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have created a custom post type for a slider (namely Piecemaker). I can add posts with featured images and descriptions, that can be used with the slider. Also, I have added a taxonomy for actually creating the sliders(sort of like a category that represents the slider ID, used for creating multiple sliders).

My problem is setting the transitions, though. The slider transitions are separate from a slider image, so they cannot be specified as meta values of posts.

So, I am thinking, what is the best way to do that. Can I somehow add the ability to specify transitions ? Notice that i don't really want to create a new custom post type to do that. It would be great to have the ability to easily add/remove and edit transitions in the same context of the custom guest post, without them being actual posts (there is no need for that really, they are just simple options).

How would you go about that ? Is there a resource that can help me with that, or a Wordpress preferred way of doing something similar ?

I know that i can always write my own implementation, like a settings panel, but apart from being an overkill, it will be kinda separated from the custom post type. I would really like a way to connect those.

Comment: I think in this situation what most people do is add a meta box to the custom post type. In that you can set up options. Pending on what you know about programming in WordPress and php, there are a few different ways you could do it. Drop down list, checkbox, text box or maybe even a shortcode. There are lots of tutorials out there on how to add a meta box to WordPress

Comment: thanx Jamie.I know how to add meta boxes,but the problem is that these meta boxes are tied to the post type, in this case the slider image. However, in my case, these transitions are not tied to the image, but the actual slider, which is just represented by a category name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are grouping the slides in a taxonomy then you can add "custom fields" to that taxonomy term. 
take a look at [this tutorial](http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way) to add te fields to the taxonomy term edit form.

Comment: A link only is considered poor quality :)

Comment: @kaiser that is way i added an expiation :)

Comment: Dude, the tutorial on adding extra fields to the category is just what I needed for a project that I am working on. I was wondering how I could get a picture posted for a category and you have just the solution. I subscribed.